# connect hostinger DB with nodejs in local

Tags: node.js, database

I have created a database in Hostinger and make it remote. But, when I try to connect with my local using nodejs I am getting an error: "ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR" even after using the right username and password.

This is my code below:

[image]

Have I done anything wrong? Please help me

Comment: Are you sure they allow connections to that DB from all origins ?

Comment: I am not so sure.

Comment: Try connection using a external sql tool like workbench

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs if the credentials are incorrect or the user can not access the database.

Also, In an express app, it is usually better to re-use the database connection instead of connecting to the database on every request.

Comment: But, I have created the database and using the right credentials. In spite of that is there any possibility I am not able to access it from my local